# Ubertcart 3.x price per role

Tags: 7, ubercart

I would like to set different prices for different userroles. My main is goal is to set "list price" as price to userrole1, and "sell price" to other users. The "list price" is the retail price and I would like to allow to some users to buy on that price.

As I was researching I came to the conclusion to do it by theme_uc_price(), but this function has no accesss to the sell_price. It gets only a $variable['price']. I think it would be the best practice to push the list price somehow to this function.

```
function theme_uc_price($variables) { 
  global $user;
  if (in_array('userrole1', $user->roles)) {
    $variables['price'] = $here_should_come_the_list_price_but_how; /* missing var */
  }

  $output = uc_currency_format($variables['price']);
  if (!empty($variables['suffixes'])) {
    $output .= ' ' . implode(' ', $variables['suffixes']);
  }

  return $output;
}
```

My other plan was to modify the theme_uc_product_price(), it really works, but only on the node pages (teaser and full view). On the cart and checkout pages it switches back to sell price, because those pages do not load the theme_uc_product_price().

```
function theme_uc_product_price($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $price = $element['#value'];
  $attributes = isset($element['#attributes']) ? $element['#attributes'] : array();
  $label = isset($element['#title']) ? $element['#title'] : '';

  if (isset($attributes['class'])) {
    array_unshift($attributes['class'], 'product-info');
  }
  else {
    $attributes['class'] = array('product-info');
  }

  $output = '';
  if ($label) {
    $output .= '' . $label . ' ';
  }

  /* get list_price - 'hack' starts from here */
  global $user;
  if (in_array('userrole1', $user->roles)) {
    $node_id = substr($element['#attributes']['class'][1], -4, 4);

    $result = db_query('SELECT list_price FROM `dr_uc_products` WHERE nid = '.$node_id);
    foreach($result as $item) {
      $price = substr($item->list_price, 0, -6);
    }
  }

  $vars = array('price' => $price);
  if (!empty($element['#suffixes'])) {
    $vars['suffixes'] = $element['#suffixes'];
  }

  $output .= theme('uc_price', $vars);
  $output .= drupal_render_children($element);
  $output .= '';

  return $output;
}
```

Any tip or advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You question seem unclear. Are you trying to sell roles with different prices?

Comment: Sorry for that. I will rewrite my question to make it clear. What I want to achieve is: users in userrole1 group can only see and use "list price" which is less and other users can see and use "sell price" which is more. 
And my problem is, I dont really know, where should I set this rule.